# Discord.js Ticket system error send is undefined error

Tags: discord.js

The problem I am having is that send is undefined even though I used message.guild.channels.cache.get
which is all the properties of message to get a channel by ID so I don't know what I forgot to add that made it undefined.

````
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const moment = require("moment-timezone");

module.exports.run = (client, message, args) => {
message.guild.channels.create(`ticket-${message.author.username}`, {
    permissionOverwrites: [
     {
      id: message.author.id,
      allow: ['SEND_MESSAGES', 'VIEW_CHANNEL'],
     },
     {
      id: message.guild.roles.everyone,
      deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
     },
 {
      id: "727622663769554948",
      allow: ['SEND_MESSAGES', 'VIEW_CHANNEL'],
     },
 {
      id: "768569229603373146",
      allow: ['SEND_MESSAGES', 'VIEW_CHANNEL'],
     },
    ],
    type: 'text',
   })

let created = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setTitle("Ticket created!")
.setDescription("Your ticket has been created")
.setFooter("DevHub | Your everyday help")
.setColor("BLUE")


message.channel.send(created)

let newchannel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === `ticket-${message.author.username}`);
message.guild.channels.cache.get(`${newchannel}`).send('Test');
    }

module.exports.help = {
  name: "tcreate"
};```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is the new Version of Discord.js

Just Replace this:

```
message.guild.channels.cache.get
```

to this:

```
message.guild.channels.cache.fetch
```